# Why aren't my bootstrap 4 columns the same height?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm just learning bootstrap 4. The columns are supposed to be the same height, but that's not working out. 
Code:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xl-8">
     <div class="projectDescBox">
       <h5>Project</h5>
       <p>Stuff here</p>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
     <div class="projectDescBox">
       <h5>heading</h5>
       <p>a lot longer stuff here. This box should be a lot longer.a lot longer stuff here. This box should be a lot longer.a lot longer stuff here. This box should be a lot longer.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

(it's in a class container further up). According to the documentation, it should be automatically the same height. However, here is my output: 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLMOp.png)

What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 29):

You're columns are most likely the same height. It's the `projectDescBox` that's not. Use the **`h-100`** class (`height:100%`) to make the inner boxes fill the height.

```
<div class="projectDescBox h-100">
       <h5>heading</h5>
       <p>a lot longer stuff here. This box should be a lot longer.a lot longer stuff here. This box should be a lot longer.a lot longer stuff here. This box should be a lot longer.</p>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/d8lGpPzUOy

Also, `col-xs-*` has been replaced with  `col-*` in Bootstrap 4. The multi-tier classes are also unnecessary since there all the same width at each tier.

**this:** `col-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xl-8`,

**is the same as:** `col-8`

You only need to have multi-tier classes when you want different widths at each tier (eg: `col-8 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3`)

Comment: I would also add that if the first column has a size o 8, the second one will have a size of 4 (12 - 8). It is not necessary to specify it. The result is "col-8" for the first column and "col" for the second one.